# Why XLOOKUP formula does not work with implicit wild cards?

Tags: excel-formula, xlookup

In the following example the implicit wild cards do work when COUNTIF is involved.

> =XLOOKUP(1,1/COUNTIF(D2,"asterisk"&A1&"asterisk"),B1)

[image]

Please explain why it doesn't work int he following manner

> =XLOOKUP(D1,"asterisk"&A1&"asterisk",B1,,2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The order of the arguments is different for all the various `...IF()` functions and the `XLOOKUP()` function:

`=COUNTIF( range , lookup_value)`

`=XLOOKUP( lookup_value , lookup_range , return_range )`

You correctly added the wildcard match_mode to the XLOOKUP.  But you need to re-swizzle your arguments to be:

`=XLOOKUP( "*"&A1&"*" , lookup_range, return_range , , 2 )`